# (jQuery) Clone variable content into a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which `onClick` will append the content before an element. But instead, I need to append the content to the **closest parent** div of the button. (.content div)

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/680u7p2m/)

```
$('#layoutTextArea').click(function(){
         var toAppend=$('#appendTextArea').children();
         toAppend.clone().insertBefore('#layoutCanvas');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="layoutCanvas">
  <div class="content">
      <p>
      On click of the button append within "content" div
      </p>
      <button id="layoutTextArea" class="btn btn-primary">Click Here</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-none" id="appendTextArea">
   <h1>
   Test Block
   </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) might help you with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target. In your code the target is `#layoutCanvas`.

Change the target to `$(this).parent()`:

```
toAppend.clone().insertAfter($(this).parent());
```

Though I prefer this with `parent()` and `appned()`

```
$(this).parent().append(toAppend.clone());
```

```js
$('#layoutTextArea').click(function(){
     var toAppend=$('#appendTextArea').children();
     $(this).parent().append(toAppend.clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layoutCanvas">
  <div class="content">
      <p>
      On click of the button append within "content" div
      </p>
      <button id="layoutTextArea" class="btn btn-primary">Click Here</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-none" id="appendTextArea">
   <h1>
   Test Block
   </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```js
$('#layoutTextArea').click(function(){
         var toAppend=$('#appendTextArea').children();
         toAppend.clone().insertAfter($(this).parent());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="layoutCanvas">
  <div class="content">
      <p>
      On click of the button append within "content" div
      </p>
      <button id="layoutTextArea" class="btn btn-primary">Click Here</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-none" id="appendTextArea">
   <h1>
   Test Block
   </h1>
</div>
```